# how can i scroll between many textfield and textarea on uiscrollview?

Tags: iphone

i have an nsarray of textfields and another of textarea. I have also a toolbar with next and previous button to manage navigation between my fields. I made a fonction in textfieldDidBeginEditing and another in textfieldDidEndEditing but it didn't work correctly.
my function is :

if (textField.frame.origin.y > 180) {

```
    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIScrollView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

    [UIScrollView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGFloat updatedY = 150;

    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.origin.x,self.scrollView.frame.origin.y - updatedY, self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                       self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use this one

```
 - (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
 {
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:.30];

      [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textView];

      [UIView commitAnimations];
      return YES;
 }


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:.30];

      [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];

      [UIView commitAnimations];

      return YES;

}


- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView
{
    CGFloat y ;
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;

    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    CGFloat avaliableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 250;

    y = viewCenterY - avaliableHeight / 2.0f;

    if (y < 0)
    {
        y = 0;
    }
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y)];
}
```

Comment: thanks Dharmbir, your solution worked fine for portrait mode but not on landscape mode.

Comment: Your Welcome Dear.And Yes its only for portrait mode.

Comment: Which one is answer is accepted my dear.You have accepted  kirti's answer.If you got your answer then plz accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Keyboard handler. The one I am using is a very good keyboard handler.

[Keyboard Handler by Sukhpal Singh](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/514396/Keyboard-Handling-in-iPhone-Applications-Part-2-2)

This is a very good tutorial from one of my good friend and You can use this.

For using this you just have to write a single line of code.

```
 AutoScroller * scroller=[AutoScroller addAutoScrollTo:self.scrollView isDoneToolBarNeeded:NO];
```

yes its done.

Comment: Also if that solves your problem mark it as answer. And help the community to resolves other's issues.

Comment: Thanks Avtar for your help but il seems that this method work only without isdoneToolBarneeded and i want  to apply my own toolbar with next and previous options

Comment: NO, It also works with done toolbar just use. [AutoScroller addAutoScrollTo:self.scrollView isDoneToolBarNeeded:Yes]. But Yes it will add a toolbar with done button above the keyboard as input accessory view and on done button click the keyboard will hide. And if you want to add your own toolbar then I am afraid that this method will not be usefull for you as it handles all delegates on return key of keyboard. And i don't think that you need next and previous key by using this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{


        [clientscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textField.center.y-180) animated:YES];



}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [clientscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

        [clientscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,textView.center.y-180) animated:YES];



}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [clientscrollview resignFirstResponder];
    [clientscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];

}
```